# How to toggle a Boolean field in Firebase 9

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs3

I want to toggle a Boolean field value in Firebase 9. I'm using Vue 3

If the value of `isFav` is `true` I want to make it `false` onclick

If the value of `isFav` is `false` I want to make it `true` onclick

It works fine when I set the value of `isFav` to just `false` or `true`. But setting the value as `!isFav` doesn't work.

```html
<template>
  <!-- books list -->
  <div v-for="book in books" :key="book.id" class="book">
    <span class="material-icons fav_ico" @click="toggleFav(book.id)">
      favorite
    </span>
    <h2>{{ book.title }} ({{ book.author }})</h2>
    <div>
      <span class="material-icons done" @click="completeBook"> done </span>
      <span class="material-icons" @click="EditBook"> edit </span>
      <span class="material-icons delete" @click="deleteBook(book.id)">
        delete
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from "@vue/reactivity";
import { onMounted, onUnmounted } from "@vue/runtime-core";
import { showBooks, books } from "../use/getBooks.js";
import { doc, deleteDoc, setDoc } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/config";

onMounted(() => {
  showBooks();
});
function toggleFav(bookid) {
  const data = {
    isFav: !isFav,
  };

  const docRef = doc(db, "books", bookid);
  setDoc(docRef, data, { merge: true });
}
// Delete a Book
function deleteBook(bookid) {
  const docRef = doc(db, "books", bookid);

  deleteDoc(docRef);
}
</script>
```

**Console**

> Uncaught ReferenceError: isFav is not defined

Maybe I'm not reading the value of `isFav` first. But how can I do that?

Comment: there must be a refrence for `isFav`, where you get it from. try using 'isFav' in data object.

Comment: Please `edit` your question and add your complete code so we can see where existing value of `isfav` is coming from.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the prompt reply. I added the Vue code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass current value of `isFav` to `toggleFav` as shown below:

```
<span class="material-icons fav_ico" @click="toggleFav(book.id, book.isFav)">
```

Then use `updateDoc()` to update the existing document as shown below:

```
async function toggleFav(bookid, isFav) {
  const docRef = doc(db, "books", bookid);
  await updateDoc(docRef, { isFav: !isFav });
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer. I used setDoc and it works fine. Is updateDoc better than setDoc?

Comment: @meawcoding `updateDoc()` is meant to use to update existing docs. `setDoc({}, { merge: true })` is usually used for upsert operations where you want to create documents if it does not exists or just update if it does.